# query correta de sql não funciona no php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Eu tenho uma query, onde essa query funciona perfeitamente no mysql workbench, porém no php não funciona.

```
$dados = explode("-",$ids);

$sql = "SELECT 


                    prt_produto_item.nome as nome_item,
                    prt_produto_item.qtd_referencia as qtd_referencia,
                    prt_produto_item.valor_referencia as valor_referencia,
                    prt_produto_item.valor_unitario as valor_unitario

                    FROM prt_produto_item_modulo_tipo

                    JOIN prt_produto_item ON prt_produto_item_modulo_tipo._id_produto_item = prt_produto_item.id_produto_item 
                    JOIN prt_produto_tipo_licenciamento ON prt_produto_item_modulo_tipo._id_tipo_licenciamento = prt_produto_tipo_licenciamento.id_tipo_licenciamento 
                    WHERE prt_produto_tipo_licenciamento.nome = '".$dados[1]."' AND prt_produto_item.nome = '".$dados[0]."';";
            $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);

            echo $stmt->execute();
               print_r( $stmt->fetchAll());
```

Ele executa bonitinho, porém ele me dá de retorno um array vazio.

Quando eu tiro o prt_produto_item.nome = $dados[0] ele funciona direitinho no php.

Obs: os dados de $dados = explode("-",$ids); estão vindo perfeitamente

**Alteração - resultado do echo sql**

```
SELECT 


                    prt_produto_item.nome as nome_item,
                    prt_produto_item.qtd_referencia as qtd_referencia,
                    prt_produto_item.valor_referencia as valor_referencia,
                    prt_produto_item.valor_unitario as valor_unitario

                    FROM prt_produto_item_modulo_tipo

                    JOIN prt_produto_item ON prt_produto_item_modulo_tipo._id_produto_item = prt_produto_item.id_produto_item 
                    JOIN prt_produto_tipo_licenciamento ON prt_produto_item_modulo_tipo._id_tipo_licenciamento = prt_produto_tipo_licenciamento.id_tipo_licenciamento 
                    WHERE prt_produto_tipo_licenciamento.nome = 'Comercial' AND prt_produto_item.nome = 'Até';
```

O retorno da mesma query, no sql
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**minha class DB**

```
class DB{
    private static $instance;
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            try
            {
                self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME , DB_USER, DB_PASS) ;
                //self::$instance->exec("set names utf8");
                self::$instance->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            } catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }


    public static function prepare($sql){
        return self::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se assim aparece algum erro: `if(!$stmt->execute()){ print_r($stmt->errorInfo());}`. No pior dos casos o encode pode estar errado aí masca aquele acento.

Comment: Não apresentou nenhum erro cara

Comment: Ele simplesmente não encontra nada

Comment: Coloque na pergunta a implementação da classe `DB`.

Comment: coloquei já....

Comment: E o retorno de `$stmt->execute()` é `False`?

Comment: não, ta vindo true, só está me retornando vazio, como se não tivesse encontrando, mas quando execute essa mesma query no gerenciador do banco de dados funciona perfeitamente

Comment: Já testou com alguma palavra diferente do `Até`, que não tenha acentos?

Comment: Não, o problema que eu preciso que seja exatamente essa palavra

Comment: Mas vou testar com outras palavras, para ver se encontra

Comment: Tente: AND prt_produto_item.nome = '".utf8_encode($dados[0])."';";

Comment: já testei para ver se estava dando pau no acento, não está, vindo certinho :(

Comment: Cara, coloquei utf_decode... deu certo

Comment: Show... se não quiser usar utf8_encode em tudo, coloque a aplicação e a base de dados com o mesmo encoding ou adiciona o seguinte parametro para o PDO:

$this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Comment: Beleza, depois vou dar uma padronizada no sistema de novo, acho que só ai que deu pau no acento